# Doesn't ThreadPriority.Highest guarantee finishing before ThreadPriority.Lowest?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-priority

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
class MultiThreading
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MultiThreading mul = new MultiThreading();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mul.WriteX));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mul.WriteO));

        t1.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        t2.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

    }

    private void WriteX()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("X");
        }
    }

    private void WriteO()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("O");
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I execute above code, I expect X's end of the printing job because I gave that method lowest priority but sometimes I get O's at the end. I mean doesn't giving high priority to 2nd thread guarantee it will finish sooner?

Comment: Maybe with a cpu with only 1 core, but good luck finding one in a modern computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no practical guarantee about thread scheduling induced by the priority setting.

For example, the high priority thread could block on IO or a page fault. Then, another thread can execute.

This is not a good way to synchronize threads.

Answer (score 1):

Three hundreds operations for CPU is part of second. I recommend you to think about your problem and applications as a statistical experiment.

Repeat your experiment many times, because running few of them is not trustworthy. It happens because population (number of iterations it is not big enough). I tried to run this application few times, but with 3 000 000 iterations and I let to write for 45 seconds (while(true) and Thread.Sleep(45000)). Task with higher priority finished first.

Your OS, CPU and PC configuration does matter.